# What to call an "academy research fellow"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, academic-latin

I started today in a new position called "academy research fellow".
The title means that I hold a specific five-year grant aimed for research and starting a research group, and is roughly the same career stage as tenure track.
The grant is given by the Academy of Finland, the national funding agency (not a learned society).

How can I translate this title into Latin?
If [Vicipaedia](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regalis_Societas_Londini) is to be trusted, fellows of the Royal Society are called *sodales*, so perhaps that would be a reasonable word for "fellow".
*Academia* or the derived *academicus* sound like reasonable components to use as well.
I am not sure how to translate "research" naturally and most importantly how to compose it all into a single coherent title.
How would you go about translating it?

The Finnish and Swedish versions of the title (akatemiatutkija, akademiforskare) translate to "academy researcher".
The Academy operates in these three languages, so no other official translations exists as far as I know.
Dropping the term "fellow" is not out of the question if it makes a good title.

Comment: Perhaps this is an abuse of the comment function, but...congratulations!

Comment: @brianpck That's a welcome form of abuse. Thank you!

Comment: [I've been looking for a similar term](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/21084/any-idea-whats-going-on-with-the-middle-term-of-this-dedication). From [this source](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rstl.1714.0065), it looks like the G.F. might have something to do with being a _fellow_ at Exeter, one of the Oxford colleges. I'm sure they have called themselves _something_ in Latin that would be more accurate in this context than the RSS. Even so, I can't find it from Google.

Comment: @lly Interesting! I think it would be best to ask a separate question about Latin titles for fellows (and maybe others) at Exeter. A question specifically about Exeter might attract answers.

Comment: Maybe, in that newer questions without answers attract more eyes. It really is just a request for _exactly_ the same word you were asking for here, though, I think. My linked thread also already asked about G.F. as an abbreviation there. I don't think I should start a third thread xD but you're welcome to if you really think it would be helpful.

Comment: @lly I don't think this question is about the same title at all. An academy research fellow is someone who has been funded by a specific national funding instrument for a 5-year period and is relatively young (never tenured, for example), whereas a fellowship at a college at Oxford or Cambridge is essentially permanent but unfunded. If anyone (you or me or anyone else) wants to learn about the British kinds of fellowships in Latin, we should certainly have a separate question.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta [Pretty sure that's wrong](https://www.lib.cam.ac.uk/university-archives/glossary/fellow): fellows have always had funding ('fellowship') and you're just possibly talking about the funding coming from an impersonal modern national gov't instead of an endowment, local association, or grant from some monarch. Seems 6 of one to me. Still welcome to start a new thread if you see an angle for it.

Comment: @lly It's a side issue, but I agree that fellowship comes with *some* funding. I just meant it's essentially unfunded in comparison: College fellows do get some support but not full salary, as they are mostly paid by their departments instead of their colleges. (This is at least my impression from my time spent at Cambridge.) An academy research fellow is funded by their fellowship in full, requiring no other source of salary. There are various kinds of fellowship out there, and they are related. My point was merely that these two are not *exactly* the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In "academy research fellow" the main word is "fellow" and the two others modify it.
In Latin those modifiers become adjectives, "academy-related" and "research-related".
This could be *academicus* and *investigatorius* or *inquisitorius* if "researcher" is *investigator* or *inquisitor* as my Finnish–Latin–Finnish dictionary suggests.

Thus my best translation for the moment is ***sodalis inquisitorius academicus***.
I don't know if this has any precedent, though.